# PHP and Fusion Chart API problem

Tags: php, charts

I'm working with the Fusion Chart Free API for PHP. The docs state that you can generate a chart from any type of database query, but when I attempt to pass a result other than an mySQL result. However when I try this: 
$FC->addDataFromDatabase($result, "SALES", "ITEM");
Where $result is a valid DB2 result set, I get this error.

"mysql_fetch_array(): supplied resource is not a valid MySQL result" error"
Anyone know how I tell Fusion charts to use a different database type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.fusioncharts.com/forum/Topic7278-31-1.aspx#bm7290) post on their forums indicates that they only support MySQL database results at this moment. You could use one of there other methods to supply data or extend the addDataFromDatabase function yourself.